# Java - Populating an ArrayList gives null pointer error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In my class I define:

```
private ArrayList<BlockObject> blocks;
```

And later:

```
blocks.add(new BlockObject(x, y));
```

However I get this error

```
02-22 17:06:52.672: E/AndroidRuntime(479): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 17:06:52.672: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.comp1008.hhh.uuu.Scenario.blocks(Scenario.java:41)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private ArrayList<BlockObject> blocks = new ArrayList<BlockObject>();
```

You have to initialize your object.

Comment: Oh man, that was blazing fast and amazingly easy. I am new to the language, very much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

you have to `initialize your arraylist` before you populate it.

```
private ArrayList<BlockObject> blocks = new ArrayList<BlockObject>();
```